# Unique Constraint performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, data-warehouse, unique-constraint

When having a table with 450 million records and a unique constraint (no primary key, just constraint made out of 6 columns), how can I improve its performance while inserting 5 million rows daily.

at the moment I just disable the constraint and enable it after the loading has finished. But this takes some time.

By the way, there is no unique index supporting the constraint... it will just get super huge

Comment: "By the way, there is no unique index supporting the constraint..." - what do you mean by that? There has to be an index behind the constraint. Or you mean that you have non-unique index behind that constraint?

Answer (score 3):

In case your import procedure ensures uniquenes of new rows you can enable the constraint with `NOVALIDATE`, then existing data in the table are not checked.

See here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204

Comment: So this will only check the "new" rows for violations?

Comment: If you enable with NOVALIDATE it checks only records which are inserted after you enabled the constraint. Any existing data are not checked.